# Regular expression getting two numbers in string

Tags: java, regex

I have a code like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([,].*[,]\\s)(\\d+)");

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

String a = "insert into dpma_dp_t (dp_id, dp_identifier, dp_model_key, group_id, description, suppressed_reason, is_qualifiable, changed_by, changed_at) values (3, 'dag', 'ALG0DAY', 2, 'Prio 0', 'ANS01', 'False', 100, 1);";

Matcher m = p.matcher(a);

if (m.find()) {     
   m.appendReplacement(buffer, "'$1'$2'$3'");
}

m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println(buffer);
```

It tried to replace the value for the `dp_id` and the `group_id` for `'3'` and `'2'` respectively.

However I am getting this as output:

> insert into dpma_dp_t (dp_id, dp_identifier, dp_model_key, group_id, description, suppressed_reason, is_qualifiable, changed_by, changed_at) values ('3', 'dag', 'ALG0DAY', 2, 'Prio 0', 'ANS01', 'False', 100, '1');

The `dp_id` and the `changed_at` are replaced.

I am new to regex and I am stuck in this. I have tried all combinations I can think of for the regex but none works. The problem is I don't see the problem, I feel this regex is fine and should do the work: finds an area in the string that matches (digits) as group 1 + (comma + anything + comma + space) as group 2 + (digits) as group 3.

Could some one guide me on how to construct a right regexp here? What is my error?

Comment: I strongly advise you to learn about [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-).  It would make this entire string replacement issue irrelevant, and will also protect your application against SQL injection exploits.

Comment: I asked just how to replace the string using regular expressions. What makes you think I am going to execute any sql? This goes into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a SQL query, there're APIs for that.
If you just wanna use the regular expression, this might be what you are looking for:
`(\\d+)([,].*?[,]\\s)(\\d+)`, to put a ? after *

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to replace the regular expression. It works with the ? after the *, tks. But... What does the ? after the * changes? Could you please tell me the difference?

Comment: Question mark means ungreedy, http://regular-expressions.mobi/repeat.html